# Transform a txt file to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nlp, lemmatization

Assuming a following text file (lemma_es.txt) is present:

comer coma 
comer comais 
comer comamos 
comer coman

The first column represents the lemma of the second column and the second column represents the inflected word.

I am trying to make a dictionary in which the keys are the words in the second word and the values are the words in the first column.

The output I need:

{'coma': 'comer', 'comais': 'comer', 'comamos': 'comer', 'coman': 'comer' ... }

**Edit**: The txt starts with:

1 primer 
1 primera 
1 primeras 
1 primero

There are some words that's need to be duplicated, only in dictionary's values, first column of words in txt.

Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could use:

```
with open('lemma_es.txt') as f:
    d = dict(reversed(l.strip().split()) for l in f)
```

output:

```
{'coma': 'comer', 'comais': 'comer', 'comamos': 'comer', 'coman': 'comer'}
```

*NB. note that the second words must be unique*

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try this:

```
myfile = open("lemma_es.txt", 'r')
data_dict = {}
for line in myfile:
    k, v = line.strip().split()
    data_dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()
 
myfile.close()
 
print(' text file to dictionary =\n ',data_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
word_dict={}
with open("lemma_es.txt","r") as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle.readlines():
        word_dict[line.split()[-1]]=line.split()[0]
```

Read the txt file and read each line using readlines . Split the line and Just use the second value of list as key.

Comment: I get this output:
{'primer': 'ï»¿1',
 'primera': 'primero',
 'primeras': 'primero',
 'primero': '1',
 'primeros': 'primero',
 'decima': '10',
 'decimas': 'decima',
 'decimo': '10',
 'decimos': 'decir',
 'centesima': '100',

Do you know how to fix it ?